# Is there a way to access relationship attributes as own in laravel model?

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, relationship

I have 2 tables: ***users*** and ***users_details***

-- users has 3 columns [id,username,password]

-- users_details has [id,user_id,name,address]

I have models for each of them with a relation from users to users_details.

```
    public function details()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserDetails::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

my question comes here: Is there a way to access UsersDetails attributes as User only.

e.g: **{{ $user->name }} : {{ $user->address }}**
instead of **{{ $user->details->name }} : {{ $user->details->address }}**

Keep in mind that these tables are only examples and don't have their real range of columns. I need this to implement Laravel/Cashier but this plugin needs 4 new columns in [users] table and I want to put them in [users_details] table.

I haven't tried anything because I don't really know if it is possible. Except for the moment the only workaround that I know of is to make getNameAttribute method in User:

```
    public function getNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->details->name;
    }
```

Comment: @bhoomi-patel thanks for the edits :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I would recommend it as it will just add *magic* to how things work and might be hard to understand 6 months from now.

But you could do something like that in your User model.

**Edited**

```
public function getAttribute($key)
{
    // If attribute exists on the user, return that
    return parent::getAttribute($key)
        // otherwise fallback to details attribute
        ?? optional($this->details)->getAttribute($key);
}
```

Comment: Laravel is so full of magic I'm not sure this adds any noteworthy confusion. Document your models and you should be okay. Nice solution btw!

Answer (score 2):

yes.
you can do it in controller before pass `$user` to your view.
like this.

```
$user->load('details');
```

then you pass the `$user` to your view like this:

```
return view('your_view' , compact('user'));
```

then in your view use the following code:

```
{{ $user->details_table_field }}
```

you can search about eager loading : 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Thanks but I needed this in the model itself not in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

I think using `Laravel Query Builder` and `Laravel Scope` is also another option in this problem.

To do that you need to add the following line of codes.

In your User Model:

```
public function scopeUserDetails($query){
    return $query->join('users_details', 'users.id', '=', 'users_details.user_id');
}
```

In your Controller:

```
$users = User::userDetails()->all(); #get all users
//dd($users); #dumping results
return view("view_file", compact('users')); #passing data to view
```

In your Blade View File:

```
 @foreach ($users as $user)
      {{ $user->name }} : {{ $user->address }}
 @endforeach
```

Comment: This is usefull I could use it like Global scope and the data will always be available to $user